# Add auto_increment unique id to my sql?

Tags: mysql, alter

I have already created table in MySQL and want to add a column i.e, 'myid' to table i.e, 'mytable'.

There is already **primary key** defined.

I use follwing query to add auto increment:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD myid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE;
```

But I want that the auto increment should start from 30 rather than 1.

**What modification to query required? Any other way to add this?**

**Secondly if i use following procedure,**

First i run query: `ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 30;`

Then run `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD myid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE;`

will it be okay? yes or no?

Comment: First add the autoincrement column and then alter it to 30.

Answer (score 1):

If your table is empty or very small then first add the AUTO_INCREMENT column and then set it's start value like this:

Make `myid` as `AUTO_INCREMENT` column:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD `myid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE;
```

Set its start value to `30`
ALTER TABLE `mytable` AUTO_INCREMENT = 30;

### Caveat

If you have lots of records in `mytable` and you use

```
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 30;
```

MySQL server will create a new table, copy all the data from the old table to the new, delete the old and then rename the new one even though there is no structural change to the table. The server response will show that all the rows have been `affected` like this:

mysql> alter table mytable auto_increment = 30;
Query OK, 609481 rows affected (1 min 4.55 sec)
Records: 609481 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0

There are potential issues that may arise from the table copy e.g. insufficient amount of free disk space for the second copy of the data.

Trick you can use to just insert a dummy row and explicitly set the AUTO_INCREMENT column to 29, then immediately delete the dummy row. The next row that is inserted will start at 30 and values will go upwards from there.